# swapping two key/value pairs in Dictionary of C#

Tags: c#, dictionary, swap, key-value

here is what I want to do.

there is a Dictionary having 54 key/value objects. I want the key/value pair at index i to be swapped with the key/value pair at index j...

```
int i=1; int j=3;
Dictionary<String, int> theDeck = new Dictionary<String, int>();
theDeck.Add("zero",  0);
theDeck.Add("one",   1);
theDeck.Add("two",   2);
theDeck.Add("three", 3);
KeyValuePair<String, int> p1 = theDeck.ElementAt(i);
KeyValuePair<String, int> p2 = theDeck.ElementAt(j);
theDeck.ElementAt(i) = p2; //THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK. WHAT IS ITS ALTERNATIVE
theDeck.ElementAt(j) = p1; //THIS LINE DOES NOT WORK. WHAT IS ITS ALTERNATIVE
```

Comment: I don't understand why you would need to do this in a dictionary?  Ordering in a dictionary isn't necessary, since the KEY is how items are accessed.  Nothing about accessing your dictionary will change based on the ordering of the KeyValuePairs.

Comment: actually what I need is a specific number against a string.
and I also want to swap these pairs, in order I want.
can you help me with it ??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Dictionary<,>` instances don't *have* "indexes" - you shouldn't treat them as ordered at all. Any order you may happen to notice when iterating over entries should be seen as an implementation detail.

If you want a *specific* order, there are various different types you could use, depending on your requirements. For example, to sort based on the key you'd use [`SortedDictionary<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) or [`SortedList<,>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx). For arbitrary ordering, consider [`OrderedDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.ordereddictionary.aspx) (which is unfortunately non-generic).

Do you definitely need a dictionary at all? Could you just use a `List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>` or perhaps a `List<Card>` where `Card` is a custom type? (I'm guessing at your use case - `Card` could be any type which represents everything in your entry.)

Comment: its the same error with List<KeyValuePair<string, int>>
check this link
[link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9pUOYW1Jzt0ZkljTmxXcE9LeXM/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Asadullah: Yes, I wasn't saying that you could *just* swap for `List<T>` - you can never assign to the result of a method call. But there's no point in us writing correct code that doesn't meet your requirements... (For a `List<T>`, you'd just use the indexer instead of using `ElementAt`.)

Answer (score 0):

Make mirroring (the 2nd) dictionary, and use it as a key source. Combine in 3d dictionary, while processing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.This worked for me.

First convert dictionary to list then find indexes of objects to be swapped.After swapping convert list back to dictionary.

`var list = someDictionary.ToList();`

`int indexA = list.FindIndex(objA=> (condition));`

`int indexB = list.FindIndex(objB => (condition));`

`list.SwapListEntries(indexA, indexB);`

`someDictionary=list.ToDictionary(obj => obj.Key, obj => obj.Value);`

Comment: too extensive and useless processing when better options are already available

Comment: Will you please list better options just for my knowledge.Thanks

Comment: I have no other option other than dictionary and I want to perform swapping please guide.

Comment: Swapping implies that you need something ordered. Dictionary is not ordered. Why don't you give Jon Skeet's approach a try?

Comment: Oh understand it.Thanks